# Angular routing with dynamic part in it

Tags: angular

I have an angular site with many routes, for example:

```
/orders
/products
/customers
```

etc...
Now I want to make my project handle multiple companies, where the url should be:

```
/companyA/orders
/companyB/orders
etc...
```

I can change the routes to be:

```
:company/orders
```

But I would prefer to just tell angular that its route root is /:company (where the company is determined by the first url I used).

Any tips on how to do that? I have many routes and I don't want to change them all manually

Comment: not clear what the problem is here

Comment: True. Explained in his answer

Answer (score 1):

With a help from a friend I reached this solution:
https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Which has solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can simply nest the routes like this:

```js
{
    path: ':company',
    component: DummyComponent, // You'll need some dummy component here
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'orders',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'orders',
            component: OrderComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'products',
            component: ProductsComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'customers',
            component: CustomersComponent,
        }
    ]
}
```

This will cover all routes like companyA/orders or companyB/products

Comment: How will that affect all the navigate to route that I have in my application? will I need to adjust them?

Comment: If they navigate to e.g. companyB/products, you won't need to adjust anything.